# Record List Component Community Builder

Tags: community, community-builder, napili

Currently trying to use the Number of Records property on Record List component within Community Builder(Napili Template). I've set the property to 5, I would expect that it will limit the number of records that will be shown in the record list component.

[image]

But it still keep on showing all of the records within the list. Is this a bug? or am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter is applicable only for the Compact Layout and not Full.If you select Full view the Number of records property is not applicable .

Change the layout to compact to observe changes .

Comment: That's why it doesn't work, Thanks!